# SIGINT in python using button

Tags: python

I am struggling with my work on how could I power on/off the script with only using the button only. I was planning to use only button for my work, I had researched and so far all of it doesn't work on me. Well running the python script with a button works for me but terminating it with a SIGINT command or ctrl+c, I don't want to force kill or terminate the command bacause of the reason having a KeyboardInterrupt condition at the end of my main script. I don't know what cause to be the problem. I tried several suggestions from other forums so most likely my script was modified several times.

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import SIGINT
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import time
import os
import signal
import sys

start = Button(24)
devnull= open('/dev/null', 'w')

def interrupt_handler(sig, frame):
    sys.exit(1)

while True:
    if start.is_pressed:
        start.wait_for_press()
        proc=subprocess.Popen('python bruh_sorting.py', stdout=devnull, shell=True)
        time.sleep(2)
        start.wait_for_release()
        pid = proc.pid
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
        time.sleep(2)
```